# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core

Tags: android

I have a problem about google firebase, failed to resolve

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

how can I solve this? I just follow instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set 2 different versions in same implementation. It should be

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

or

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
```

but not both.

Answer (score 1):

**This is add your manifests**

```
       <service
            android:name=".notification.service.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:stopWithTask="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

**This is add your gradle**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the last part of the version number for the dependency i.e you should have this instead 
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1